# Random information from API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

with my team we are working on a project that require to retrive posts on user home. We are using the PHP-SDK (last version) and the Graph API for retrive the information; but the problem isn't this, the php script is perfectly working, but there is an issue: every time i refresh the page, facebook give us different information...an example:

```
$home_posts=$facebook->api('/me/home?limit=20');
foreach($home_posts['data'] as $home_posts){
  operation...
}
```

Sometimes on a limit of 20 posts it gives us 10 posts, sometimes 15, sometimes all 20 postes etc...
Or doesn't give a post, or give different information...
It's like facebook gives random informations :S

The Graph API Explorer facebook tool give sometimes this problem too (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), it returns a different number of post or doesn't give a post etc...

It's very strange and is a very boring problem for those want to create a service that use Facebook API

Someone can help us? Someone has encountered this issue? I think there is a problem in facebook API system, but reading the Platform Status give ever Facebook Platform is Healthy.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  I am only able to get two distinct listings back when making that call.  So it's less random than my calls, as for the same call I get back one of two data sets.  You should report it to http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Done, is here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/132356006887098?browse=search_4f3eb36c7567c2a81312383, i hope someone can help us